# Istio K8sObjectOverlay.PathValue list elements not working

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I had an existing instance of [IstioOperator](https://istio.io/v1.5/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/) installed from Istio v1.5:

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio
spec:
  profile: default
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - namespace: istio-system
        name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          serviceAnnotations:
            "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type": "Internal"
            "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal": "0.0.0.0/0"
            "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal": "true"
            "external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname": "*.SedTarget"
  addonComponents:
    kiali:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: false
```

This worked fine.

I added the following section in the `k8s` section (under `spec.components.ingressGateways[0].k8s`):

```yaml
          overlays:
          - apiVersion: v1
            kind: Service
            name: istio-ingressgateway
            patches:
            - path: spec.ports.[name:kafka]
              value:
                name: kafka
                protocol: TCP
                port: 9092
                targetPort: 9092
```

So that I could add `kafka` to list of ports.

This did not work, even though [the docs show I should be able to specify something like `[name:kafka]` to add an element to a list](https://istio.io/v1.5/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#K8sObjectOverlay-PathValue):

> #### K8sObjectOverlay.PathValue
>
> Field - Path of the form `a.[key1:value1].b.[:value2]` Where `[key1:value1]` is a selector for a key-value pair to identify a list element and `[:value]` is a value selector to identify a list element in a leaf list. All path intermediate nodes must exist.

**I believe this is not due to a typo, because I *am* able to replace an existing element in the list with the `kafka` patch by specifying a path like `spec.ports[1]`**. I am not able to specify an existing port to overwrite it with any `[key:value]` pair, and `spec.ports[-]` does not work for appending to the end of the list.

This does not match my expectations. Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please find the examples of patch operation in the following test file: https://github.com/ostromart/istio/blob/7aa3a6b82426309123f21964675803d2cf5b5697/operator/pkg/tpath/tpath_test.go

Answer (score 3):

I spent some time learning this and got the `tls` service to work.

First, sounds like you are missing the `|` in the YAML override.

```yaml
          overlays:
          - apiVersion: v1
            kind: Service
            name: istio-ingressgateway
            patches:
            - path: spec.ports.[name:kafka]
              value: |  <== here
                name: kafka
                protocol: TCP
                port: 9092
                targetPort: 9092
```

You can get more info by looking at the operator logs. For example:

```
$ kubectl -n istio-operator logs istio-operator-5998f6c744-kg2v6
```

and you should see something like this:

```
2020-06-20T06:20:28.200545Z info    installer   Applying Kubernetes overlay:
- kind: Service
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  patches:
  - path: spec.ports.[name:kafka]
    value: |
      name: kafka
      port: 9092
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9092
```

However, this doesn't seem to override the port and I get (even if I manually add the kafka port to the `istio-ingressgateway` K8s service):

```
2020-06-20T06:37:01.388907Z error   reconciling err: path spec.ports.[name:kafka]: element [name:kafka] not found
```

It does work with something existing like `spec.ports.[name:tls]`.

Now, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do by modifying the ingress gateway service. As I understand these overrides are meant for specific Istio components and not how you 'use' Istio per se.

Typically, to add a gateway/service with Istio you would use something like [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#configuring-ingress-using-an-istio-gateway) with `Gateway` and `VirtualService` resources.

Comment: Hey Rico, thanks for taking a look. First, you are right about the `istio-operator` logs; I get the same error and I should have included that. Second, while I think you are more correct about the `|` after value, it appears to work correctly without the `|` when specifying an index rather than a key-value pair, so I guess they're pretty permissive there.

Comment: sounds good. I guess it's flexible when it comes to specifying the `|`

Comment: As for why, I'm cribbing off https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7242#issuecomment-406808437